# Pandas replace non-zero values

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can replace all nan values with `df.fillna(0)` and replace a single value with `df.replace('-',1)`, but how can I replace all non-zero values with a single value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```
df[df != 0] = value
```

Comment: @pyCython your edit used [chained assignment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) so I reverted it.