# Replace non-zero values in a pandas dataframe with 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe 'result'. One of the attribute in this data frame is 'transaction' which contain value like 0 if it's a non cash transaction and some real number if transaction is cash transaction.This attribute look like:

```
result['transaction'] = [0,0,0,23.2,432,12,0,0,56.4]
```

I want to change the value of this attribute such that all non-zero values will be replaced by 1. So my resultant attribute should look like this:

```
result['transaction'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021909/pandas-replace-non-zero-values

Answer (score 9):

Another option could be to use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert to `bool` and then `int`.

```
df.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Which outputs

```
   transaction
0            0
1            0
2            0 
3            1
4            1
5            1
6            0
7            0
8            1
```

In my experience this approach has proven to be quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

Original dataframe:

```
df
    col1
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3   23.2
4  432.0
5   12.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8   56.4
```

---

#### `df.where`

You can use `df.where` to filter and assign:

```
df.col1 = df.where(df.col1 == 0, 1)
df
   col1
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   1.0
```

---

#### Boolean Indexing

You can also use `boolean indexing` with a simpler predicate:

```
df[df.col1 != 0] = 1
df
   col1
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   1.0
```

---

#### `df.map`

```
df[df.col1.map((0).__ne__)] = 1
df
   col1
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   1.0
```

Note that, for every method, you can tack on a `.astype(int)` if you want to get rid of the floating point part of your output.